# How to make cloudKit on watchOS work with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: ios, swift

hI'm trying to use Cloud sync using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. I have a watch target which uses the same container. the watch is not able to talk to cloud because of some reason. I have attached the logs below.

```
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitOptionsValidator validateOptions:andStoreOptions:error:](35): Validating options: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateOptions: 0x80740f60> containerIdentifier:iCloud.pleaseWorkplease.please ckAssetThresholdBytes:<null> operationMemoryThresholdBytes:<null> useEncryptedStorage:NO automaticallyDownloadFileBackedFutures:NO automaticallyScheduleImportAndExportOperations:YES skipCloudKitSetup:NO preserveLegacyRecordMetadataBehavior:NO useDaemon:YES apsConnectionMachServiceName:<null> containerProvider:<PFCloudKitContainerProvider: 0x80740d20> storeMonitorProvider:<PFCloudKitStoreMonitorProvider: 0x80740dc0> metricsClient:<PFCloudKitMetricsClient: 0x80740e10> metadataPurger:<PFCloudKitMetadataPurger: 0x80740eb0> scheduler:<null> notificationListener:<null> containerOptions:<null>
storeOptions: {
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptionsKey = "<NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions: 0x8022b690>";
    NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreMirroringOptionsKey =     {
        NSPersistentStoreMirroringDelegateOptionKey = "<NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>";
    };
    NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationOptionKey = 1;
}
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _setUpCloudKitIntegration](417): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Successfully enqueued setup request.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](2077): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Checking for pending requests.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest]_block_invoke(2089): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Executing: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateSetupRequest: 0x803239c0> BFD081CA-F584-4AFA-9557-CFAEA75AD496
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](298): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKDATABASEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZLASTFETCHDATE'
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](298): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKDATABASEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZHASCHANGES'
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](312): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKMETADATAENTRY' because it already has a column named 'ZDATEVALUE'
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](298): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKRECORDZONEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZLASTFETCHDATE'
CoreData: debug: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitMetadataModelMigrator calculateMigrationStepsWithConnection:error:](298): Skipping migration for 'ANSCKRECORDZONEMETADATA' because it already has a column named 'ZHASCHANGES'
WatchOs
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[PFCloudKitSetupAssistant _checkUserIdentity:]_block_invoke(722): <PFCloudKitSetupAssistant: 0x800329c0>: CKIdentity record matches store: <CKRecordID: 0x8073e420; recordName=_b3114a44a09f407e191dfb0cf25dbe30, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
2020-02-16 15:23:13.385282+0530 WatchApp Extension[4324:334645] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _performSetupRequest:]_block_invoke(837): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Failed to set up CloudKit integration for store: <NSSQLCore: 0x8022d440> (URL: file:///Users/bibinbenny/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8859107F-74B0-43DA-8E2F-96BE1E73601C/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/AEB34FF5-6EF4-41AD-83BB-5FC3800900CA/product.sqlite)
<CKError 0x80738280: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"; partial errors: {
    com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
}>
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _performSetupRequest:]_block_invoke(837): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Failed to set up CloudKit integration for store: <NSSQLCore: 0x8022d440> (URL: file:///Users/bibinbenny/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8859107F-74B0-43DA-8E2F-96BE1E73601C/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/AEB34FF5-6EF4-41AD-83BB-5FC3800900CA/product.sqlite)
<CKError 0x80738280: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"; partial errors: {
    com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
}>
2020-02-16 15:23:13.387633+0530 WatchApp Extension[4324:334645] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate recoverFromError:](1492): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0> - Attempting recovery from error: <CKError 0x80738280: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"; partial errors: {
    com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
}>
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate recoverFromError:](1492): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0> - Attempting recovery from error: <CKError 0x80738280: "Partial Failure" (2/1011); "Failed to modify some record zones"; partial errors: {
    com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone:__defaultOwner__ = <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
}>
2020-02-16 15:23:13.389357+0530 WatchApp Extension[4324:334645] [error] error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _recoverFromPartialError:withMonitor:]_block_invoke(1739): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Found unknown error as part of a partial failure: <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
CoreData: error: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _recoverFromPartialError:withMonitor:]_block_invoke(1739): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Found unknown error as part of a partial failure: <CKError 0x807537d0: "Internal Error" (1/5000); "Failed to sync user keys">
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _finishedRequest:withResult:](2106): Finished request: <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegateSetupRequest: 0x803239c0> BFD081CA-F584-4AFA-9557-CFAEA75AD496 with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x80127310> success: 1 madeChanges: 0 error: (null)
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](2077): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: Checking for pending requests.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest]_block_invoke(2092): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x807407c0>: No more requests to execute.
```

Comment: did you resolve this? I see it in the simulator and I _think_ it's because I'm not properly logged into iCloud on the watch. On the one hand on the watch it shows my name in settings as if I'm logged in, on the other it does sometimes ask for my password which is very hard to enter on the watch

Comment: watch simulator doesn't include an account. Was this fixed? Check your entity, and container names to code.

Comment: The same happens also in Xcode 14.0. The simulator is broken again. It works with the device.